# Get data from the database into the main django admin page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

i want to put some data from the database into the admin index page, so i am trying to add some code to the `index.html`, but the commands such as `Model_name.object.get()` don't seem to work there

```
<ul>{% trans 'Last Update at ' %}
    {% for entryupdate in Updatetime.objects.all %}
            {{ entryupdate.updatetime }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

so what shall i use instead? The problem is that there is no variable associated with the object i need. If that would have been any other page i could have added the variable in the `views.py`, but that's not the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sorts of functions don't work in *any* template.

You should use a custom template tag to query the data and return it.

Comment: Not true, that function would work just fine in a template, assuming the Updatetime class was passed as a variable to the template.

Comment: how can i pass that class as a variable to the template index.html? i need to change the view of the /admin/ main page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the tip of Daniel i created that tag:

```
import datetime
from django import template
from Myapp.models import Updatetime

register = template.Library()

def update_time():
    ss = Updatetime.objects.get(pk=1)
    str11 = ss.updatetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return str11

register.simple_tag(update_time)
```